# Initialising properties in a subclass?

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I have a subclass of a subclass as i require a variation on a varients behaviour based on a base class.

The issue im facing is that this new subclass requires some custom values that need to be initialised in an init method.

The situation is:

I have a value e.g. `let time: Dynamic<String?>` where I have to use `let` due to the binding method

and so i need to provide a value in an init in order to compile...

but as the class signature looks like this: `class NewViewModel: DurationViewModel<Model>`
the superclass is also `class DurationViewModel<T: Model>: BaseViewModel<T>`

I dont seem to be able to use `convenience init` or `init` with a call to `super`

Is there a correct way to achieve this so i can initialise these `let` constants in this subclass

Comment: I don't understand the question, could you elaborate with a minimal viable example?

Comment: Im not sure what to add, this is minimum example, a property that needs to be initialised, but due to being a sub class of a subclass, i cant have an init method just for this subclass and its properties

Comment: Clearly I'm not getting it. Could you please sketch it out in some pseudo-Swift? Where are the properties, what the initializer like so far, etc.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include actual code (as text) that fully demonstrates your issue. People should be able to copy and paste your code into a playground and replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand. Does this not work for you?

```
class Parent {
    let someVar: String

    init() {
        someVar = "Some value"
    }
}

class Child: Parent {
    let someOtherVar: String

    override init() {
        someOtherVar = "Some other value"
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: nope thats my issue, it throws 'Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass' and 'Cannot invoke 'DurationViewModel<Model>.init' with no arguments'